# A leaky bucket and water leaks out at a rate of 1/4 lb/s. My logic is wrong.

Tags: calculus

A 5 lb bucket containing 10 lb of water is hanging at the end of a 30 ft rope which
weighs 1/2 lb/ft. The other end of the rope is attached to a pulley. The rope is wound
onto the pulley at a rate of 3 ft/s causing the bucket to be lifted. Find the work done in
winding the rope onto the pulley if the water leaks out of the bucket at a rate of 1/4 lb/s.

I got most of it. Only part I am stuck is calculating the work for leaky water. Here is my solution and apparently it is wrong. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my logic?

[image: My solution]

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is over the distance lifted, so the upper limit should be $30$

Comment: Ok, you are right but that is not it.In the solution whole equation is multiplied by 3.   [link](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/leaking%20bucket.pdf)

Comment: Your 1/4 pound leakage iis per second, not per foot, so needs to be corrected.  That will get a factor $3$ on that term